# How to cache streaming video and silverlight with squid windows reverse proxy

Tags: squid, reverse-proxy, video-streaming

We have an intranet web server running a silverlight application (ACTUS media monitor if anyone cares to know).

The server is used to record video and stream it to clients through a CDN solution.

We want to put a reverse proxy in between the server and CDN provider in order to remove the office network bottleneck that's currently strangling us.

I've set up SQUID for windows on a separate machine outside the network using squid [BasicAccelerator](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/BasicAccelerator) configuration setting.

It seems to work as far as the reverse proxy is concerned, requests are forwarded and the application is working but it doesn't seem to cache anything (no space is used on the drive where squid is installed).

I found to explicit setting to turn caching on in squid, so i assume it's on by default. Perhaps I need some other trick to make the video and/or silverlight cacheable?

Any help will be appreciated. Any info you need to help me will be provided at once.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some fiddling I figured it out.

The silverlight application is irrelevant, all it does (as far as the proxy is concerned) is fetch dynamic HTTP content.

What I needed besides the basic setting was a refresh_pattern that looks like this :

```
refresh_pattern -i \.ashx 10080 90% 999999 ignore-no-cache override-expire ignore-private
```

Now I know a tiny bit more about proxy setup and how it works. Woohoo!